# Good way to get file locations when the location of the python script looking for the file can change?

Tags: python, file-io, directory

I have a folder 'pyMS' that contains scripts with doctests. Also in pyMS is a folder 'test' which has both unit tests and a folder 'testfiles' that contains files with data that I use for testing.

```
pyMS/
├── __init__.py
├── baseFunctions.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test_baseFunctions.py
    └── testfiles
        └── testfile.txt
```

I want to use the unittest to run the doctest with

```
suite.addTest(doctest.DocTestSuite("baseFunctions")
```

However, I'm running in the problem when I try to use files in the doctest.

This would work when doing the doctest from the commandline (python baseFunctions -v):

```
testfile = open('test/testfiles/testfile.txt')
```

but when running it from the unittest it gives an IOError because the test_baseFunctions.py is in the test folder, so the correct location for the file is /testfiles/testfile.txt instead of test/testfiles/testfile.txt.

My very ugly solution now is

```
import os
testfile = open(os.abspath('').split('pyMS')[0]+'pyMS'+os.sep+'test'+os.sep+'testfiles'+os.sep+'testfile.txt'
```

What would be a better way to handle this?

Comment: Don't forget about the magic `__file__` attribute: it stores the location of the script, meaning you can write various handles to the ambiguous `testfile.txt` in every directory a unique `testfile.txt` appears, each with its own set of instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can standardize by doing an `os.chdir()` to the appropriate place. For running tests, I can't think of any reason not to.